# Full page div overlay blur not showing

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm new into angular projects and I want to set a Div to a component to blur all page size

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="div-general">
  <!-- All <app-components> -->
</div>
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(4px);
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What happens when you use the code you've provided?

Comment: Welcome to SO @robgher . Without knowing the question I have taken my best bet at answering the problem below. When posting a question in SO you should state the problem you are having. In this case a screenshot would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS's `filter: blur()` only blurs the content of the targeted DOM element (and its children/subtree).

It does not affect siblings, even if your overlay has a higher z-index.

You can work around this by either:

- Applying `filter: blur()` to your `.div-general` instead, or
- Applying something other than `filter:blur()` on your overlay div, like [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter).

```css
.div-general {
  filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="div-general">
  <!-- All <app-components> -->
  <p>Sample text</p>
  Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text Sample text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO Rob.

The width and height will only fill the width and the height of the container. The solutions would either be to make sure that the container that .overlay sits inside is the full width and height of the viewport or to use `vw` for the width and `vh` for the height instead of `%`:

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  filter: blur(4px);
  z-index: 2000;
  }
```

`vw` is a percentage of the viewport width and `vh` is a percentage of the viewport height.

Comment: This is the first thing I thought of, but it is not the OP's issue. Did you try running this CSS in a snippet?